# Angular - http post ReportProgress returns undefined event if http interceptor is enabled and modify response

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do upload file and wants to show the upload progress but at the same time I have custom HTTP interceptor to modify my response body as a result it's not getting HttpEventType.UploadProgress rather than it's returning undefined. But, if I removing HTTP interceptor it works perfectly.

Here is the code sample I created on CodeSandbox, not sure what I'm missing.

[Code Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dew-wjqim)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue :) I'm using a map to modify my response and return back I forgot return after my if condition. I have updated my code sample in CodeSandBox as well.

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  map((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    
    if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
      // hide my loader
      if (ev.body.status !== undefined) {
        const resp = ev.body as IDefaultResponse;

        if (!resp.status) {
          console.log(resp.errorMessage);
        } else {
          const response = ev.clone({
            body: resp.data
          });

          return response;
        }
      }

    }

    return ev; // << this is what I missed :)
  }),
  catchError((response) => {
    if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      switch (response.status) {
        //Error number for example: 500, 400 etc.
        case 0:
          console.log(response.message);
          break;
      }

      return observableThrowError(response);
    }
  })
);
```